# Suppress title tooltip of SVG in Angular

Tags: html, angular, svg

The SVG `<title>` is displayed as a tooltip on hovering over the SVG icon.

```html
<div [inlineSVG]="'icons/forward-small.svg' | assetUrl"></div>
```

[image: tooltip displayed on hovering over the SVG icon]

I don't want this tooltip (forward-small) to be displayed on hovering over the SVG arrow icon. I tried to set (`title=""`, `matTooltip=""`, or `alt=""`) but didn't work. ai I want also to add a click listener on the SVG.

How can I suppress this tooltip without deleting the title element from the SVG file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine by adding the following styles to styles.scss file and it's also possible to add click listeners on the SVG:

```css
    svg {
      vertical-align: sub;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN docs:

> Text in a `<title>` element is not rendered as part of the graphic, but
> browsers usually display it as a tooltip.

Browsers will use this `<title>` as a tooltip. One workaround would be to disable any `pointer-events` on the entire svg.

```
div svg{
pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Note:** Use it if you don't want any click listeners on the SVG.

**Option 2:**

> How can I suppress this tooltip without deleting the title element
> from the SVG file?

You can manipulate the SVG by inserting an empty `<title></title>` before the actual `<title>`

```
let svg=document.querySelector('svg'); //Select your SVG
svg.querySelectorAll('title').forEach(item=>{
  item.parentElement.innerHTML='<title></title>'+item.parentElement.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: Actually, I want to add a click listener on the SVG. Also inserting an empty `<title></title>` before the actual `<title>` doesn't work as expected because it shows me an empty tooltip.